# For Update - for psycopg2 cursor for postgres

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, cursor, psycopg2

We are using psycopg2 jsonb cursor to fetch the data and processing but when ever new thread or processing coming it should not fetch and process the same records which first process or thread.

For that we have try to use the FOR UPDATE but we just want to know whether we are using correct syntax or not.

```
    con = self.dbPool.getconn()
    cur = conn.cursor()             
    sql="""SELECT jsondoc FROM %s WHERE jsondoc @> %s"”"             
    if 'sql' in queryFilter:                 
   sql += queryFilter 'sql’]   
   When we print this query, it will be shown as below:             
         Query: "SELECT jsondoc FROM %s WHERE jsondoc @> %s AND (jsondoc ->> ‘claimDate')::float <= 1536613219.0 AND ( jsondoc ->> ‘claimstatus' = ‘done' OR jsondoc ->> 'claimstatus' =                    'failed' ) limit 2 FOR UPDATE"         
 cur.execute(sql, (AsIs(self.tablename), Json(queryFilter),)) 
    cur.execute()
    dbResult = cur.fetchall()
```

Please help us to clarify the syntax and explain if that syntax is correct then how this query lock the fetched records of first thread.

Thanks,
Sanjay.

Answer (score 1):

If this exemplary query is executed

```
select * 
from my_table
order by id
limit 2
for update; -- wrong
```

then two resulting rows are locked until the end of the transaction (i.e. next `connection.rollback()` or `connection.commit()` or the connection is closed). If another transaction tries to run the same query during this time, it will be stopped until the two rows are unlocked. So it **is not** the behaviour you are expected. You should add `skip locked` clause:

```
select * 
from my_table
order by id
limit 2
for update skip locked; -- correct
```

With this clause the second transaction will skip the locked rows and return next two onces without waiting.

Read about it in [the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html)

Comment: Thanks Klin, but my requirement, once the first thread pull the records and start processing, the second thread should not fetch at all those records, it should fetch the remaining unlocked records.

Comment: Yes, `skip locked` is exactly doing that.